# Finding $A { \cap } B $ when $A=\{ (x, y):x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$ and $B=\{(x, y):x^6+y^6 = 1\}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$A=\{ (x, y):x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$$ and $$B=\{(x, y):x^6+y^6 = 1\}$$ Also, x and y are real numbers **greater** than **zero**.

I want to find  $A { \cap } B $.

ie. I want to check whether it is A, B or the null set.

Now, I don't know how to do this problem. However, I had this intuition that it might be a null set.

So, what I did was,

Let $x^2 = a, y^2 = b$

( I am trying to find a common term in both A and B. Which means $a+b=a^3+b^3=1 $)

So, $x^2=1-b$  $,since$ $ x^2+y^2 = 1$

So,

$x^6+y^6=1$ $ \implies $$a^3+ b^3 =1$

= ${(1-b)}^3 + b^3 = 1-3b+3(b^2)$

Clearly this is not equal to one. ie. There are no common terms in A and B. So,
$$  A { \cap } B = \phi  $$

Can I use this method? Could anyone explain how I can approach this problem using a better method?(since, if my guess turned out to be wrong, I wouldn't have been able to proceed).

Thanks

Comment: "*Clearly this is not equal to one*" $\;-\;$ You must prove this, not just state it.

Comment: This is a geometry/algebra problem, not a set theory problem.

Comment: Oh!  Not giving the justification for that statement was a tremendous error from my side. I apologise deeply.Well, I got some really really impressive answers anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like how your method peters out into a "Clearly this is not equal to one". Why is $1 - 3b + 3b^2 \neq 1$? It actually is equal to $1$ for certain $b$, but which ones? Are they relevant to the problem?

You should solve $1 - 3b + 3b^2 = 1$. If you do, you get $-3b + 3b^2 = 0 \iff 3b(1 - b) = 0$, which is true if and only if $b = 0$ or $b = 1$. So, indeed, there are $b$ that satisfy this condition. But, if you consider $y^2 = b$, then $b = 0$ gives us $y = 0$, contradicting $y$ being positive. If you consider $y^2 = 1$, then $y^2 = 1 = x^2 + y^2$, so $x^2 = 0$, contradicting $x$ being positive. Thus our only two possible solutions produce nothing sensible for our problem, from which we can conclude that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Alternatively, consider that, if $(x, y) \in A \cap B$, and so $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then
$$0 \le x^2 \le x^2 + y^2 = 1,$$
so $x^2$ lies between $0$ and $1$, and similarly for $y^2$. Therefore,
$$0 = 0\cdot x^2 \le x^2 \cdot x^2 \le 1 \cdot x^2 \le 1 \implies 0 \le x^4 \le 1.$$
Thus,
$$0 \cdot x^2 \le x^4 \cdot x^2 \le 1 \cdot x^2 \implies x^6 \le x^2,$$
and similarly for $y$. So, if $(x, y) \in A \cap B$, then
$$1 = x^6 + y^6 \le x^2 + y^6 \le x^2 + y^2 = 1,$$
which means that all the inequalities would have to be equalities, i.e. $x^2 = x^6$ and $y^2 = y^6$. This once again leads to $x^2, y^2 = 0, 1$, in some order, which is impossible, since both $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Answer (score 2):

We have $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. Trying our damnedest to find as much $a+b$ in there as we can, this gives us
$$
x^6+y^6=(x^2+y^2)(x^4-x^2y^2+y^4)\\
=(x^2+y^2)(x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-3x^2y^2)\\
=(x^2+y^2)((x^2+y^2)^2-3x^2y^2)
=1(1^2-3x^2y^2)<1
$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't find anything wrong with your method.

But, as you said, you had the intuition that it would be a null set (which is absolutely correct), I would just suggest you look up the graph of
$$x^n+y^n=1$$
(especially for the even values of $n$) and remember the pattern. It's quite a popular graph, and exams often assume you know it.

If you just look at the graph, you'll see that the only solutions are $\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\}$. But, since the question says, $x$ and $y$ are strictly greater than $0$, you don't have any solutions.

Comment: Why the null set is correct ?

Comment: @jimjim as I said, just look at the graph and see that the only solutions are $\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\}$. But, since the question says, $x$ and $y$ are strictly greater than $0$, you don't have any solutions.

Comment: Looking at the graph is not a proof , it doesn't explain why those are the only solutions and nothing else

Comment: @jimjim The OP did give a formal proof of the set being null, right?

Comment: No, he just made a statement that this is clear that some expression is not equal to 1 without showing why . Making statements that are not clear why is not mathematics. In this case it was lucky that intuition and theorem was same, but that does not mean they were correct to just say it without proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your working is fine. To make it look slightly more presentable, maybe you can express your answer as follows:

Suppose, for contradiction, there exists $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}) \in A\cap B$. Since $(a,b)$ is an element of $A$, $b = 1-a$.

Then, since $(a,b)$ is also an element of $B$,
$$
a^3 + b^3 = 1\\
a^3 + (1-a)^3 = 1\\
3 a(a-1) = 0 \\
a = 1 \text{ or } a = 0
$$

$a=0$ is not a valid solution since $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$. If $a=1$, then $b=0$, which is also invalid since $b\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Thus, there is no $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}) \in A\cap B$, leading to a contradiction.

$\therefore$ $A\cap B = \emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(x, y) \in A$.

Observe that $x, y \in (0, 1)$. You state in passing, though not in the comprehensions that define $A$ and $B$, that all coordinates of members of $A$ are positive; so $x, y \neq 0$. But if $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and either of $x,y$ is $1$, then the other must be $0$, so $(x, y) \notin A$.

Thus, $0 \lt x \lt 1$, so $0 \lt x^2 \lt 1$, from which we see that also $y^2 = 1 - x^2 \lt 1$. But $x^6 = x^4 x^2 \lt 1 x^2 = x^2$, and similarly $y^6 \lt y^2$, so $x^6 + y^6 < x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Thus $(x, y) \notin B$.

Therefore $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: you are correct if set A were set of real numbers. But set A and B are defined for positive real numbers. Kindly correct your answer

Comment: Corrected this to reflect this additional requirement.